# Index match formula matching within a time range

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, match

I've 2 table -

table 1

| Datetime | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 09/04/2023 11:25:00 |  |
| 09/05/2023 11:20:00 |  |
| 09/06/2023 11:30:00 |  |
| 09/07/2023 11:30:00 |  |
| 09/08/2023 1:30:00 |  |
| 09/09/2023 12:00:00 |  |
| 09/10/2023 8:58:00 |  |

table 2

| Datetime | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 09/05/2023 10:55:00 | karim |
| 09/07/2023 10:30:00 | karim |
| 09/06/2023 11:35:00 | rahim |
| 09/07/2023 10:30:00 | rarim |
| 09/04/2023 11:25:00 | alex |

I want to combine this two table, if the difference  between `Datetime` column of `table 1` and `Datetime` column of `table 2` is around 30 minutes.

My table should looks like

| Datetime | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 09/04/2023 11:25:00 | alex |
| 09/05/2023 11:20:00 | karim |
| 09/06/2023 11:30:00 | Rahim |
| 09/07/2023 11:30:00 | not present |
| 09/08/2023 1:30:00 | not present |
| 09/09/2023 12:00:00 | not present |
| 09/10/2023 8:58:00 | not present |

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
=XLOOKUP(1,(@[Datetime]>Table2[Datetime]-1/48)*(@[Datetime]<Table2[Datetime]+1/48),Table2[Name],"Not present")
```

[image]

*Explanation*

The formula is placed in the first row of Table 1, under Name.

`@[Datetime]` refers to the value in the same row in the Datetime column, which contains `09/04/2023 11:25:00`

`Table2[Datetime]-1/48` creates an array of the values in the Datetime column of Table 2, but with half an hour (1/48 of a day) subtracted.

`(@[Datetime]>Table2[Datetime]-1/48)` compares the datetime from Table 1 with all of the datetimes in the array generated in the previous step and creates a true/false array of these values which looks like

F F F F T

`(@[Datetime]<Table2[Datetime]+1/48)` does the same thing as the previous expression but with half an hour added to the datetimes in Table 2, giving another array which looks like

T T T T T

`(@[Datetime]>Table2[Datetime]-1/48)*(@[Datetime]<Table2[Datetime]+1/48)` means that the true/false arrays are AND'ed together (but when working with arrays you have to use * ,the multiplication operator, and the result is a number, 1 or zero) to give

0 0 0 0 1

Now you can feed all this in to [Xlookup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) and it will find the first match in the array for '1' and return the corresponding name from Table 2 which in this case is 'Alex' unless there is no match in which case it will return "not present".

Because the formula is entered into a table, it will be automatically copied down to all rows of the table, in each case selecting the Datetime in the cell to the left of each cell in the Name column of Table 1.

Note that the formula suggested by @DS_London removes the step of creating two arrays and ANDing them together, but creates an array

F F F F T

then looks up the value 'True' in this array.

Comment: Maybe `=XLOOKUP(TRUE,ABS([@Datetime]-Table2[Datetime])<=(30/(24*60)),Table2[Name],"not present")` is a little more concise?

Comment: can you explain the formula please ? i'm totally new in excel @Tom

Comment: Yes, I will add an explanation to my answer.